# set mat-select field in combination with interface

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'll set up a selection field. The selected value should be stored in a service to be seen after reloading the browser. As you can see, the event.value (if selected), this.categories[2].value and ['79_facet_obj_type'] are identical.

To set a default value at the beginning of ngOnInit for the select field, only the value this.categories[2].value works.  . Why is this so ? The console shows the identical values of the three objects!

Because I want to store the selected value in the service with the function onSelectChange() and then retrieve it when the page is reloaded with ngOnInit, I have the problem that I can only work with event.value.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

**TextComponent.ts**

```
export class TextSearchComponent implements OnInit {
        
queryText: string;
            
categories: Category[] = [
   { value: ['_all'], viewValue: 'Volltext' },
   { value: ['79_analyse_aktuell', '79_analyse_kirchen'], viewValue:'Art des Objektes' },
   { value: ['79_date'], viewValue: 'Datierung' },
];
        
selectedCategory = this.categories[0].value; // init default value
    
constructor(private queryBuilder: QueryBuilderService,) { }
    
ngOnInit() {
   

    
if (this.queryBuilder.getSort() !== undefined) {
    this.selectedCategory = this.queryBuilder.getSort();
    }

}
    
onSelectChange(event) {
  this.queryBuilder.setSort(event.value);
}
```

**TextComponent.html**

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="w-100">
      <mat-select placeholder="category" (selectionChange)="onSelectChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" name="category">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.value">
          {{category.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**query-builder.service**

```
  public setSort(sort) {
    this.savedSort = sort;
    console.log(this.savedSort);
  }

  public getSort() {
    console.log(this.savedSort);
   return this.savedSort;
  }
```

Comment: Your explanation don't seem very clear to me, but there's someting smelling bad in your code. Please, try setting values as strings, not as arrays, in categories: { value: '_all', viewValue: 'Volltext' }, etc...

Comment: A little bit more simple: Why is this working -> this.selectedCategory = this.categories[5].value and this not -> this.selectedCategory = ["79_facet_kuenstler"];  The first example sets the mat-select field correct and the second not and the placeholder apear.

Answer (score 0):

It only works with this.categories[2].value because you are dealing with arrays and this.categories[2].value is a REFERENCE to an item in the same 'categories' array.
When you compare it with, say ['79_facet_obj_type'], you are comparing a reference to a value outside the 'categories' array. They have the same values, but they're placed on different parts of the memory.

Is it necessary to use arrays as values for your scenario? I think that your 'categories' array declaration is wrong. It should be:

```
categories: Category[] = [
   { value: '_all', viewValue: 'Volltext' },
   { value: '79_facet_obj_type', viewValue: 'Art des Objektes' },
   { value: '79_date', viewValue: 'Datierung' },
];
```

without putting the values inside []. That should allow to do what you want:

```
selectedCategory = '79_facet_obj_type';
```

**As per your comment:**

Then you'll have to set the selectedCategory like this:

```
selectedCategory = categories.find(elem => elem.value[0] == '79_facet_obj_type').value;
```

or some variation.

*Note: .find() requires ES6*

Comment: some of the elements in categories have multiple values { value: ['79_analyse_aktuell', '79_analyse_kirchen'], viewValue: 'Standort' },  Is there a another workarround ?

Comment: am using ES6 above. But still getting the placeholder. As you said, If i remove the array´s it works for the single values.

Comment: Try this and let me know, please:  selectedCategory = categories.find(elem => elem[0] == '79_facet_obj_type').value;

Comment: Sorry, last chance (this is for good):  selectedCategory = categories.find(elem => elem.value[0] == '79_facet_obj_type');

Comment: Sorry, using an array as value overcomplicates everything. I've no meanings to test it but, after thinking about it for a while I bet for this: selectedCategory = categories.find(elem => elem.value[0] == '79_facet_obj_type').value;  if not, I can't help anymore...